# how to show processing status of transaction or work at server side in a browser for end user?

Tags: jsp, jquery, servlets, jsp-tags

```
         ____
        ----- > 60% completed
```

the above type of some processing status i want to show the user in a web browser when these is some transaction is going.

For example im creating some tables say 1000 show i do not want to get disturb by user when some thing is going on. so for that i need to show user the status ( no. of tables created so far on the browser in a gui manner) . give me some idea to do that. in advance for ur comments and answers.

Note : while copying some data , we can see these types of graphics in windows. here i coudnt give some picture of it. hope u got what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:  Use Ajax to call the servlet that will do the processing and initialize it doing its work. Have the servlet doing the processing update a status in some database table tied to the userid/sessionid as it does the processing (or use the session object for this). Poll another servlet with Ajax to retrieve the status from that table (or session object).