# how to show / alert the status of processing of data base transaction that we done in a jsp page?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jsp-tags

[image: Examples of processing status.]

the above type of some processing status i want to show the user in a web browser when these is some transaction is going.

For example im creating some tables say 1000 show i do not want to get disturb by user when some thing is going on. so for that i need to show user the status ( no. of tables created so far on the browser in a gui manner) . give me some idea to do that. in advance for ur comments and answers.

Comment: duplicate, probably the same guy as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454488/how-to-show-processing-status-of-transaction-or-work-at-server-side-in-a-browser/ Maybe if you made a login you wouldn't lose your own questions.

Comment: yes tell me, how can i do it in jquery ?